# How to create small public/private keys using openssl and php?

Tags: php, openssl

I need to create a public/private key, but I don't need big keys, I try to use the follow code:

```
<?php
$config = array('private_key_bits' => 128);
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
?>
```

but I get this warning:

```
Warning: openssl_pkey_new(): private key length is too short; it needs to be at least 384 bits, not 64
```

Do I have to change something? (config files, modules etc etc?)

Comment: Not needing big keys and needing small keys are two different things. Why not just use a bigger key? :)

Comment: @deceze I have to save it in a cookie :-) I need a small key

Comment: are you using the key for something that needs to be encrypted (ie needs to be kept secure)?

Comment: @MD-Tech sure, in mysql I have encypted data(users table), then I have a table where I put all the logged users, in this table I saved the ID and the password (to let the users decrypt his information) BUT i can put a plain password on this table, so I have created a pair of key private/public and encrupted that password with the public so the users with his private keywords can decrypt it and get the ORIGINAL password to decrypt the information on the users table. With this system I avoid the problem of storing a key to crypt/decrypt in the php files directly.

Comment: the problem is that a key of that size will provide no security other than a tiny portion of obfuscation as the key will be breakable in minutes. If you need to keep the data secure a key of that length is pointless. I think there is probably a much better way to do what you are trying to achieve but I have to work out what it is you are trying to achieve in my head before I can suggest a solution

Comment: @MD-Tech a 128 bi key is breakable in minutes? I think is not possible because most of SSL certificate works with 128 bit.
As I told you, I generate private and public keys, I save the encrypted password (with the public key) and then I decrypt it with private key. This solution is good (to me) because I do not save the key on the DB or in a PHP file, so if someone will see the script, will never see password/keys or other eprsnal infos

Comment: sorry miniutes was hyperbole (was pushing the point) key length for secure applications should be over 1024 these days because shorter keys are breakable in relatively short time scales:
"As of 2003 RSA Security claims that 1024-bit RSA keys are equivalent in strength to 80-bit symmetric keys, 2048-bit RSA keys to 112-bit symmetric keys and 3072-bit RSA keys to 128-bit symmetric keys. RSA claims that 1024-bit keys are likely to become crackable some time between 2006 and 2010 and that 2048-bit keys are sufficient until 2030."
if you do need to use this method just surpress the warning in php

Comment: @MD-Tech however it is pointless because suppose we develop a login page that send ENCRYPTED user/password, then the other pages that check if the users is logged HOW can they decrypt the informations that are stored on the db without saving the keyword to decrypt somewhere? If i use AES and then save the key in a php file or in a config file is pointless. "my system" prevent the storing of the plain passwords..I don't know any other system.

Comment: @MD-Tech The problem should be if someone can see the php files, if the server is not very secure with this kind of system nobody can read the password in php files nor mysql

Comment: normally you dont encrypt passwords you hash them and compare hashes because your users might not want you to (potentially) know their password as they commonly use it for other systems since a hash is deterministically unidirectional it is the better solution.

Comment: @MD-Tech yes, for passwords no problem, but, what do you do if you need to encrypt email? credit card? address or other personal information? the problem is there because if someone can read the db/php files can copy all, so I must to prevent this kind of situation

Comment: as I didnt know (I'm well away from web development currently!) I looked up the size limits on a cookie and they are 4kb each and you can create upto 20 per domain you should have space for a 1024 bit key even if you do have to use a dictionary lookup system between the cookies

Comment: @MD-Tech yes I know that limit, I will investigate if this solution is good or not. if you have any advice ley me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to answer:

as I didnt know (I'm well away from web development currently!) I looked up the size limits on a cookie and they are 4kb each and you can create upto 20 per domain you should have space for a 1024 bit key even if you do have to use a dictionary lookup system between the cookies.

Also please make sure that the private key is sent using an ssl connection otherwise someone can intercept the private key and all your work will have been in vain